# how to show count the text in textarea when we drag and drop mouse and right click copy paste

Tags: jquery, tsc

Below the textarea, I want to show the remaining count of the text of textarea when we do drag and drop of the text or mouse right click copy and paste text by tsc or jquery examples ?

Answer (score 0):

I dragged from the text box to the text area.  Also included pasting.
https://jsfiddle.net/bindrid/a6czzxcy/  If I don't put it in the time out, the event is triggered before the text is received and I don't get the right count.

jquery:

```
$("textarea").on("paste, drop", 
    function(e){ 
        setTimeout(function() {
           var len = $('textarea').text().length
          $("#di").html(len);}, 0)
   });
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <textarea></textarea> <input type="text" value='source'>
</div>
<div id='di'>

</div>
```